# Why is tee process still running?

Tags: process

```
# ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  13880  4016 ?        Ss   20:40   0:00 /bin/bash
root      9646  0.0  0.0   4312   360 ?        T    21:06   0:00 tee
root     10953  0.0  0.0  47420  1660 ?        R+   21:10   0:00 ps aux
```

I logged into my machine and I saw that some processes were still running like the `tee` above. What could have caused this?

Comment: It is actually stopped. Check the state, `T`. Whats the output of `ps -p 9646 -o pid,ppid,pgid,cmd`?

Answer (score 5):

The `T` indicates that the process is "stopped". My guess is that you suspended a job (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>, or with `kill -STOP 9649`), forgot about it, and then exited.

A suspended job can be resumed

- by sending it the `CONT` signal (`kill -CONT <process_id>`), or,
- by using either the `fg` (giving the control of the session back to the process) or `bg` (resuming the job in the background, as if it was started with a trailing `&`) commands. This is possible only if the process was started in the current shell session.

In this case, I would probably just kill the job (`sudo kill 9649`). It's up to you to decide if the process is doing something important that you'd like to investigate further.

Comment: So, what do we do when the process is stopped. Ignore it? or should we kill it? And how to properly exit?

Comment: You have the user name (`root`) and the process ID (42430), so it ought to be easy to kill it:  `sudo kill 42430`

Comment: @SenthilKumaran I've expanded on my answer.